# Running if database row number is less than 10

Tags: php, database

I'm trying to make a function work only if the number in the row 'click' in my datbase is less than 10. This is what I have right now: I put the echo in there just to see if the condition is working or not.

```
<?php
include'connect.php';

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, link_name, click  FROM clicks");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if ($row['click'] < 10) {
    echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['link_name']. " " .$row['click'];
echo "<br>";
}
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try;

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, link_name, click  FROM clicks WHERE click<10");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['link_name']. " " .$row['click'];
    echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a where clause in your query?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, link_name, click  FROM clicks
where click <10");
```

Comment: I'm trying to switch the href through jquery after the link is clikced 10 times so i need to save the clicks in a database so i need the number not for it to find which row is less than 10